# Is there a limit to the length of a string for Solr fuzzy search?

Tags: solr

I try fuzzy search with Solr 8. I get the expected results for short strings, but for longer strings, there are in general no matches for fuzzy search at all. Is there a limit to how long a string can be for fuzzy search?

I add four sample queries and the log messages that show their number of hits. Note that for the long string there are hits for exact matches, but no hits, when I use fuzzy search.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/search/select?indent=true&q=item_signature:averysimpletitle
http://localhost:8983/solr/search/select?indent=true&q=item_signature:averysimpletitle~1
http://localhost:8983/solr/search/select?indent=true&q=item_signature:cantileveredtandemstatorofmoderateaerodynamicloading
http://localhost:8983/solr/search/select?indent=true&q=item_signature:cantileveredtandemstatorofmoderateaerodynamicloading~1
```

```
2024-01-25 15:45:48.572 INFO  (qtp1390301622-78) [   x:search] o.a.s.c.S.Request [search]  webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=item_signature:averysimpletitle&indent=true} hits=2 status=0 QTime=0
2024-01-25 15:45:52.582 INFO  (qtp1390301622-55) [   x:search] o.a.s.c.S.Request [search]  webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=item_signature:averysimpletitle~1&indent=true} hits=2 status=0 QTime=0
2024-01-25 15:45:58.829 INFO  (qtp1390301622-78) [   x:search] o.a.s.c.S.Request [search]  webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=item_signature:cantileveredtandemstatorofmoderateaerodynamicloading&indent=true} hits=3 status=0 QTime=0
2024-01-25 15:46:03.647 INFO  (qtp1390301622-55) [   x:search] o.a.s.c.S.Request [search]  webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=item_signature:cantileveredtandemstatorofmoderateaerodynamicloading~1&indent=true} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your string and I got the result back...

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/street_names/select?q=(street_name_clean:cantileveredtandemstatorofmoderateaerodynamicloading~1)&rows=20&wt=xml

<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">29</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="q">
(street_name_clean:cantileveredtandemstatorofmoderateaerodynamicloading~1)
</str>
<str name="rows">20</str>
<str name="wt">xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" numFoundExact="true">
<doc>
<str name="street_name">
cantileveredtandemstatorofmoderateaerodynamicloading
</str>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

Comment: Thank you, @user2260040. I tried again with a new core and it worked fine. I cannot reproduce the behaviour I described in the question in the new core.